# Flutter: How to show the first TabBar/TabBarView when returning to page?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Please view this [Demo app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOcmo.png). It has a Cupertino bottom navigation bar and on two tabs on the Products page. I've provided code snippets below (note: code mostly adapted from official docs).

**My question**
When ANY BottomNavigationBarItem item is tapped (whether it's Products, Search, or Cart), I want the index of the tab controller on the Products page to be reset to 0 and setState called on that page. How do I achieve that?

**What I'm trying to achieve**

1. When on the Products page, if I select the Right tab (tab index = 1), I want to be able to navigate back to the Left tab (tab index = 0) also by tapping on Products in the bottom navigation.
2. When on the Products page, if I select the Right tab (tab index = 1), then navigate to a different page (Search page or Cart page), then return to the Products page, I want the Left tab (tab index = 0) to be displayed by default.

Hope this makes sense. Thanks!

(Disclaimer: I'm new to both development and Stackoverflow, so I hope my question is phrased correctly. I'll be sure to amend it as I get relevant feedback).

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'products_page.dart';
import 'search_page.dart';
import 'cart_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo app',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.home),
            title: Text('Products'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.search),
            title: Text('Search'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.shopping_cart),
            title: Text('Cart'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      tabBuilder: (context, index) {
        CupertinoTabView returnValue;
        switch (index) {
          case 0:
            returnValue = CupertinoTabView(builder: (context) {
              return CupertinoPageScaffold(
                child: ProductsPage(),
              );
            });
            break;
          case 1:
            returnValue = CupertinoTabView(builder: (context) {
              return CupertinoPageScaffold(
                child: SearchPage(),
              );
            });
            break;
          case 2:
            returnValue = CupertinoTabView(builder: (context) {
              return CupertinoPageScaffold(
                child: CartPage(),
              );
            });
            break;
        }
        return returnValue;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**products_page.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProductsPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _ProductsPageState createState() => _ProductsPageState();
}

class _ProductsPageState extends State<ProductsPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 2);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              floating: false,
              pinned: true,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                centerTitle: true,
                title: Text('Products'),
              ),
            ),
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
                TabBar(
                  controller: _tabController,
                  labelColor: Colors.black87,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(text: 'LEFT'),
                    Tab(text: 'RIGHT'),
                  ],
                  // controller:,
                ),
              ),
              pinned: true,
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(child: Text('This is the left tab', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30))),
            Center(child: Text('This is the right tab', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30))),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  _SliverAppBarDelegate(this._tabBar);

  final TabBar _tabBar;

  @override
  double get minExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;
  @override
  double get maxExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: _tabBar,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add some code snippet for more clear

Comment: Have you done this?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://dev.to/fluttercorner/how-to-create-tabbar-in-flutter-complete-guide-to-make-tabbar-8b9

Comment: @Andrej that tutorial shows how to set up tabs with a tabController. It doesn't provide any solution for the above scenario though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, always set initialIndex to 0:

```
DefaultTabController(
        initialIndex: 0,
```

Comment: The initialIndex works only for when the page first builds, i.e. what tab it should default to upon first rendering of the page, but not for when it's already built (my scenario). So unfortunately it doesn't resolve this.